# Generate PDF and PDF is stored where it was generated from

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, fs, pandoc, hugo

i would love some help.

Im working on a pdf export for my Hugo site. I currently am using javascript to iterate  through all of the markdown files, turn those into Latex files , which is stored into  folder, and then those files are iterated through and turned into a pdf, which those are stored in another folder, so its messy!

**what i need help with**

i need to be able to somehow store the path of these files when theyre being made in the first place, and instead of having them put into a seperate folder all together, all unorganized, i want the pdfs to then be loaded BACK into the exact directory that it had to be generated from . HOw would i do this? like do i store the paths as a json somehow? i need very specific instructions as i am a beginner . Thank you so much

please let me know if theres any additional information you need. Thank you. I will provide the code used to iterate though the file directories in the first place.

```
 const contentPath = "../../content"
    function inner (subPath){
     
      const is_path_a_folder = fs.existsSync(`${contentPath}/${subPath}`) && fs.lstatSync(`${contentPath}/${subPath}`).isDirectory()

      if (is_path_a_folder){
        const directory = fs.readdirSync(`${contentPath}/${subPath}`)
        directory.forEach((subSubPath) => {
          inner(subPath + "/" + subSubPath) //concatinating the path keeps track
        })
      } else if (fs.existsSync(`${contentPath}/${subPath}`)) { //when its a file
        if (subPath.endsWith(".md")) {
          const filePath = `${contentPath}/${subPath}`//gets file location
          convertToTex(filePath,subPath)

        }

      }

    }
```

Comment: Not familiar with Pandoc and never (fortunately) ever had to use LaTex, but: 
https://gohugo.io/templates/output-formats/
https://gohugo.io/templates/sitemap-template/
Just output all your paths in a JSON file using output formats. 
It gives pretty detailed direction.